# How much easier on memory and CPU is headless chrome as compared to regular chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, benchmarking, headless, google-chrome-headless

I have seen many benchmarks measuring the CPU and memory utilization used by headless Chrome and PhantomJS and other headless browsers. However, I have never seen one comparing headed/regular Chrome and headless Chrome.

How much more efficient is headless Chrome than regular Chrome when doing automation/scraping on a large scale? (80 browser windows open at once, for example).